# When is it necessary to explicitly link to pthreads?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads, shared-libraries

I am building a shared library that depends on pthreads. Is it necessary to explicitly link to pthreads when building the library? I found it seems to works just fine even if I don't link to pthreads -- neither in the library nor the program using it.

Just for the sake of testing I tried this small test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int cs;
  pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, &cs);
  printf("done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I tried linking with and without -lpthread and both options work:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test 
$ ldd test
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd97ff000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3d0d936000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3d0dce1000)
$ ./test
done
$
$ gcc test.c -o test -lpthread
$ ldd test
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6518b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc0daf68000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc0dabdf000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc0db1a7000)
$ ./test
done
```

So when/why should explicitly link to pthreads ?

Comment: You should link against libpthread if you are using POSIX threading functionality. It is possible, depending on the configuration of your toolchain, that the compiler driver automatically passes `-lpthread` to the linker. This may not be portable, though.

Comment: But if gcc is passing `-lpthread` automatically, shouldn't I see the pthread dependency when I use `ldd`?

Comment: Fair enough. I'll have to think about that.

Comment: Is there a reference to the thread function left in the object code of the first case? Is pthread support actually in the C library so that `-lpthread` is unnecessary but harmless?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler readelf -s on the `test` executable shows a reference to pthread_setcancelstate. What puzzles me is that -lpthread *does* make a difference (see the output fo `ldd`), yet both options work.